# Locking cells is affecting the running of my macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a sales receipt template in excel, I have a macro to automatically save and clear certain data as well as a macro that automatically changes my sales receipt number to the next in sequence, however, when I try lock the receipt number cell along with other containing formulas and company details it stops my previous macros from working.

Please can someone assist with a solution to being able to lock these cells without affecting my previous macros?

Thanks

Comment: It means that you macro needs to change the locked cells. You will need to unlock them before launching the macro or to specify `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` when [protecting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff840611.aspx) the sheet(s)

Answer (score 0):

I would create an unlock macro that you call first to unlock the cells, then run your macro, then create and call a lock macro that locks those cells back up.